# how can I wait to function

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services

I write in node.js an html page and I want to wain in the response to the data but it to faster..
how can I create this function sync?

```
app.get('/showGuides', function(req, res) {

text = fs.readFileSync('\start.html','utf8');
text = text + '<table border="1"><tr><td>id</td><td>name</td><td>last name</td><td>address</td><td>phone</td></tr>';

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    var sql = 'select * from guides;';
    console.log(sql);
    connection.query( sql, function(err, rows) {    
        if (rows.length  > 0) {
            rows.forEach(function(row) {
            console.log('add');
                text = text + '<tr><td>' + row.id + '</td>';
                text = text + '<td>' + row.name + '</td>';
                text = text + '<td>' + row.lastName + '</td>';
                text = text + '<td>' + row.address + '</td>';
                text = text + '<td>' + row.phone + '</td></tr>';
            });
        }
        connection.end();
    });
});
text = text + '</table>'
text = text + fs.readFileSync('\end.html','utf8');

res.end(text);
});
```

Comment: You can't.  This is why Node.js is so fast.

Comment: Sure you can (wait for the response, that is), just place the three lines that are outside the async function inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this;

```
app.get('/showGuides', function (req, res) {
  fetchGuides(function (err, guides) {
    if (!err && guides) {
      var text = fs.readFileSync('\start.html', 'utf8');
      text += '<table border="1"><tr><td>id</td><td>name</td><td>last name</td><td>address</td><td>phone</td></tr>';
      text += guides;
      text += '</table>';
      text += fs.readFileSync('\end.html', 'utf8');
      res.end(text);
    } else {
      res.end('Unable to fetch guides');
    }
  });
});

function fetchGuides(cb) {
  pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    var sql = 'select * from guides;';
    console.log(sql);
    var text = '';
    connection.query(sql, function (err, rows) {
      if (rows.length) {
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
          console.log('add');
          text += '<tr><td>' + row.id + '</td>';
          text += '<td>' + row.name + '</td>';
          text += '<td>' + row.lastName + '</td>';
          text += '<td>' + row.address + '</td>';
          text += '<td>' + row.phone + '</td></tr>';
        });
      }
      cb(err, text);
      connection.end();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: its not work.. the line  text += +fs.readFileSync('\end.html', 'utf8'); is not run.. =(

Comment: Can you check again, there was a typo I just fixed.

Comment: it work!!! thanks =) what you change?

Comment: The `+` symbol before fs.readFileSync was extra, removed it. Apart from refactoring your code into two routines, I just moved the response sending code inside the query callback -- all that was needed. Are you comfortable with `jade` or `ejs` or any template script? Dynamic content are best rendered using templates, I can illustrate that modifying your code further, if you're interested.

Comment: yes it can be grate.. i read about them but not start use them..

Answer (score 0):

Hum it seems that you just want to render a dynamic html content. In this case, you may really prefer to use a template engine, it would be much simpler. As you are already using Express,  this should help:

- Set your template engine: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.engine
- Render a view (with pseudo html) http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.render and pass your result to the view. 
  Basically you just need to call `res.render('mytable.html', { rows: rows });` and in mytable.html, you'll be able to loop over your query rows, syntax depending on your template engine.

Anyway with your approach, you have to reply to the client request (i.e. res.end) inside the query callback.

Answer (score 0):

I had updated your code to make it work in my earlier post. Hope you're able to follow it well. However, dynamic content such as results retrieved from db are best handled using templates, such as `jade` or `ejs`.

I will refactor your code to demonstrate how we can do that in express using `jade` template. I have stubbed a few things to make the demo work, you can skip/modify them as you like. :)

Stand alone script to handle `/showGuides` request:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// configure other middlewares you need

app.use(app.router);

process.on('uncaughtException', console.log);

var guides = {
  process: function process(req, res, next) {
    util.log('Received request to fetch guides');
    guides.fetch(function (err, guides) {
      req.guides = guides || [];
      next(err);
    });
  },

  fetch: function fetch(cb) {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
      var sql = 'select * from guides;';
      connection.query(sql, function (err, rows) {
        cb(err, rows);
        connection.end();
      });
    });
  },

  render: function render(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.guides = req.guides;
    res.render('guides');
  },

  errors: function errors(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err);
    res.locals.errmsg = err.message;
    res.render('error');
  }
};

app.get('/showGuides', guides.process, guides.render, guides.errors);

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000);

// dummy pool -- you don't need this
var pool = {
  connection: {
    query: function (query, cb) {
      // dummy response -- simulate a db call
      setTimeout(function () {
        var dummies = [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'test',
          lastName: 'test',
          address: 'test',
          phone: 1234
        }, {
          id: 2,
          name: 'test2',
          lastName: 'test2',
          address: 'test2',
          phone: 12345
        }];
        cb(null, dummies);
      }, 500);
    },
    end: function () {
      // nothing to do
    }
  },

  getConnection: function (cb) {
    cb(null, pool.connection);
  }
};
```

Now we need to add some jade templates, namely `guides.jade`, `start.jade`, `end.jade` and `error.jade`. Add these files under dir `views`.

views/guides.jade:

```
include start

table(border="1", cellspacing="0", cellpadding="5px", width="50%")
  tr
    th id
    th name
    th last name
    th address
    th phone

  each row in guides
    tr
      td= row.id
      td= row.name
      td= row.lastName
      td= row.address
      td= row.phone

include end
```

views/start.jade

```
//- Contents from start.html

h3 Guides
```

views/end.jade

```
//- contents from end.html

p Guides data rendered.
```

views/error.jade

```
h3 Oops! An error occurred

p= errmsg
```

If you're new to jade, start with [jade tutorial](http://jade-lang.com/tutorial/). Let me know if you're unable to follow anything in the code above.

Good Day!